# Completing the loop in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arc

I am trying to complete my cyclic diagram, but my last bit of tikz code reverses my arrow direction and does not complete the diagram. I know that only my last arc is wrong, but I do not know how to fix it. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \margin {6}

\node[draw,circle] at (1*360/10:5cm) {9};
\node[draw,circle] at (2*360/10:5cm) {10};
\node[draw,circle] at (3*360/10:5cm) {7};
\node[draw,circle] at (4*360/10:5cm) {2};
\node[draw,circle] at (5*360/10:5cm) {8};
\node[draw,circle] at (6*360/10:5cm) {5};
\node[draw,circle] at (7*360/10:5cm) {4};
\node[draw,circle] at (8*360/10:5cm) {6};
\node[draw,circle] at (9*360/10:5cm) {1};
\node[draw,circle] at (10*360/10:5cm) {3};


\draw[->,>=latex] (1*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (1*360/10+\margin:2*360/10-\margin:5cm);
\draw[->,>=latex] (2*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (2*360/10+\margin:3*360/10-\margin:5cm);
\draw[->,>=latex] (3*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (3*360/10+\margin:4*360/10-\margin:5cm);
\draw[->,>=latex] (4*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (4*360/10+\margin:5*360/10-\margin:5cm);
\draw[->,>=latex] (5*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (5*360/10+\margin:6*360/10-\margin:5cm);
\draw[->,>=latex] (6*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (6*360/10+\margin:7*360/10-\margin:5cm);
\draw[->,>=latex] (7*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (7*360/10+\margin:8*360/10-\margin:5cm);
\draw[->,>=latex] (8*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (8*360/10+\margin:9*360/10-\margin:5cm);
\draw[->,>=latex] (9*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (9*360/10+\margin:10*360/10-\margin:5cm);
\draw[->,>=latex] (10*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (10*360/10+\margin:1*360/10-\margin:5cm);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if the following MWE (Minimal Working Example) is useful to you:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \margin {6}
\foreach \i [count=\j, count=\k from 2] in {9,10,7,2,8,5,4,6,1,3}
{
\node [draw,circle] at (\j*36:5cm) {\i};
\draw[-latex] (\j*36+\margin:5cm) arc (\j*36+\margin:\k*36-\margin:5cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out. The last line of code should be this:

```
\draw[->,>=latex] (10*360/10+\margin:5cm) arc (10*360/10+\margin:11*360/10-\margin:5cm);
```